# converting master node to slave node in postgresql streaming replication scenario

Tags: postgresql, master-slave-replication

I have 2 identical PostgreSQL 13 server and configured streaming replication for both server. (nodeA is master, nodeB is slave)
It working very well normally. All DML, DDL operation replicates properly

My problem is about disaster scenario. I am stopping master server like disaster
And then I am promoting slave server with following command

```
pg_ctl promote -D $PGDATA
```

And then I am testing insert/delete/update commands working properly on nodeB, it works

So I want to switch nodeA to as new slave server.
I am applying pg_rewind command to sync timeline, it worked very well too

But could not figured out how can I configure and start nodeA as new standby ?

If I could do it I will also try to switch operation again

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You turn the old, rewound master into a standby server just like you created the standby in the first place:

- set `primary_conninfo` correctly in `postgresql.conf`
- create the `standby.signal` file in the data directory
- start the server

Comment: Hello 

Sorry for delayed update, I was thinking different so my way thinking does not fit to the concept. 

Thx